# How to import json modules in webdriverio 8?

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

How to import json modules in webdriverio 8 ? It's not allowing to import json modules with webdriverio 8 integration with typescript.

```
import userdata from "../../testdata/stub/user_data.json" assert { type: "json" };
```

Getting the below exception:

```
@wdio/runner: TypeError [ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING]: Module "WebdriverIO/test/testdata/stub/user_data.json" needs an import assertion of type "json"
```